# How to make this test pass?

Tags: java

How would i make a while loop to go through the characters of the Strings of text to find the first place there is a blank and returning the value of the position. I do i need a double condition in the while loop?

```
public class TestSentenceCounter
{
private static final String SENTENCE1 = "This is my sentence.";
private static final String SENTENCE2 = "These words make another sentence that is longer";
private SentenceCounter sc1;
private SentenceCounter sc2;

/**
 * Create two instances we can play with
 */
@Before 
public void setup()
{
    sc1 = new SentenceCounter(SENTENCE1);
    sc2 = new SentenceCounter(SENTENCE2);
}
/**
 * Make sure the instance variable is correct
 */
@Test
public void testConstructor()
{
    assertEquals(SENTENCE1, sc1.getSentence());
    assertEquals(SENTENCE2, sc2.getSentence());
}
@Test
public void testFirstBlankPosition()
{
    assertEquals(4, sc1.firstBlankPosition());
    assertEquals(5, sc2.firstBlankPosition());
}
}
----------------------------------------------------
public class SentenceCounter
{
public String sentence;

public SentenceCounter(String sentence)
{
    this.sentence = sentence;
}

public Object getSentence()
{

    return sentence;
}
public Object firstBlankPosition()
{


    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Its for my Lab class and my lecture hall teacher is foreign,so the only way to really learn coding is from reddit and here, we are supposed to use a while loop to find it this is just very basic java teaching

Answer (score 0):

Update your code accordingly ,

```
public int firstBlankPosition()
{

        int returnVal = 0;
         char ch ;
           for(int i = 0 ; i < sentence.length() ; i++){
               ch = sentence.charAt(i);

               if(ch == ' '){
                   returnVal = i;
                   break;
               }
            }

    return returnVal;
}
```